# Organize bulk of PDF Files by language

Tags: windows-8, pdf

is there a way to organize 2500 PDF file as per the language of the text inside each file.
I have 2500 maintenance manual in different languages and I have them in a single folder I need to extract only the files that are in English.

found nothing on the net :-)

Thank you

Comment: Does the filename give any 'hint' as to the language such as file_en or file_es ?

Answer (score 1):

In general no. In your specific case it might be possible, but you'd have to do significant work.

### In general

I'm confident there's nothing in the PDF spec that mandates the presence of metadata indicating the primary language of the text in the PDF. Even if there was, there are so many different PDF-producing software applications that you can be sure some of them would omit it or set it to a generic value.

I'm certain you can produce PDFs from PS files which use an arbitrary text encoding. This means you cannot even guarantee that the encoding can be determined from the PDF content. Therefore you cannot be sure of being able to extract text from which to guess the language.

### Specific case

If your PDFs are all from one source, all produced using the same toolset, and have a limited range of languages, it might be possible to write a program or script to do what you want. However it is unlikely that sufficient numbers of people have this need for there to be an easily found existing solution that would work in your specific case.